# display relative data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im Having a issue with my php and mysql coding i have two tables

**table 1: haz**

```
haz_id  |  haz_description  
-------------------------
   1    |     Good

   2    |     Bad

   3    |     Great
```

**table 2: risk**

```
risk_assessment_id | haz_id | haz_id_2 | haz_id_3
-------------------------------------------------
   SF-050-PRE      |   3    |    1     |    2
```

I want to combine them so that i can get the description of each hazard in the risk table

I am not sure how to go about this i have tried everything but i cant seem to get the data, I can't be sure if the problem is coming from my join or from the echo part of the code.

code so far :

```
> $sql=SELECT risk_assessment.haz_no_id AS risk_assessment.haz_no_id,
              risk_assessment.haz_no_id_2 haz_no_id.haz_no_id AS haz_no_id.haz_no_id,
              haz_no_id.haz_description FROM risk_assessment, 
              haz_no_info 
              WHERE (risk_assessment.haz_no_id = haz_no_info.haz_no_id)
```

And This is the output  part of the code

```
> $result=mysql_query($sql); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
       echo $row['ops_id']. 
            $row['haz_no_id'].' '.
            $row['haz_description']. 
            $row['haz_no_id_2'].' '.
            $row['haz_description'];
  }
```

If anyone could help that would be great

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess What you would like to do is something like this:

DEMO : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60e686/9

```
$sql = "SELECT risk_assessment_id, h1.haz_description AS d1, " .
" h2.haz_description AS d2, " .
" h3.haz_description AS d3 " .
" FROM risk LEFT JOIN haz h1 ON risk.haz_id = h1.haz_id" .
" LEFT JOIN haz h2 ON risk.haz_id_2 = h2.haz_id" .
" LEFT JOIN haz h3 ON risk.haz_id_3 = h3.haz_id;";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: im trying to get it to echo out but for some reason its not letting me could you please help me with this part thank you ive changed the values around and in the demo it worked however when i paste it into my code it doesn't im guessing im not echoing it out properly

Comment: @user3744228 thanks. Could you share us the code you have ? I would like to see the part in which you have problem. How do you echo your values?

Comment: im echoing the code like this $row['haz_no_id'].'" "'.$row['haz_description']; thank u

Comment: and this is before the echo $result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: this is the sql code which i used and copied from yours SELECT risk_assessment.ops_id, h1.haz_description AS d1,
h2.haz_description AS d2,
h3.haz_description AS d3
FROM risk_assessment 
LEFT JOIN haz_no_info h1 ON risk_assessment.haz_no_id = h1.haz_no_id
LEFT JOIN haz_no_info h2 ON risk_assessment.haz_no_id_2 = h2.haz_no_id
LEFT JOIN haz_no_info h3 ON risk_assessment.haz_no_id_3 = h3.haz_no_id

Comment: @user3744228 thanks. BTW,I believe you don't forget to use quotation for the string: $sql = "SELECT ...";

Comment: hi thanks again for the help, i was just hopeing u can help me just one more time im so sorry about this its just your code works great but i forgot to mention that there would be up to 48 numbers in haz_id and over all 8 columns in there as well so i was wondering if there is a better way so i don't have a huge page filled with coding thank u and sorry once again

Comment: @user3744228 No problem. I guess 48 is too many to JOIN. If I were you, I would use PHP array (keys and values)to hold the information of has_description, and would not use JOIN. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT risk_assessment.haz_no_id, 
       haz_no_id.haz_description as haz_id
FROM risk_assessment, haz_no_info 
WHERE (risk_assessment.haz_no_id = haz_no_info.haz_no_id) 
ORDER BY risk_assessment.haz_no_id DESC
```

Comment: hi thank you for the quick reply but my code still doesnt seem to be working im not sure how u would echo it out i have tried both mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_array and then $row['haz_no_id'].' '.$row['haz_description'] $row['haz_no_id_2'].' '.$row['haz_description'] im not sure that is correct im not really worried about the order by part just seeing the info thank you

Comment: Try `echo $row['ops_id']. $row['haz_no_id'].'" "'.$row['haz_description']. $row['haz_no_id_2']." ".$row['haz_description'];`

Comment: hi thanks again i have tried that and it hasn't worked

Comment: Your `$row[]` variables are not the same as the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use three joins:

```
SELECT ra.haz_no_id, h1.haz_description, h2.haz_description, h3.haz_description
       haz_no_id.haz_description as haz_id
FROM risk_assessment ra left join
     haz_no_info h1
     on ra.haz_id1 = h1.haz_id left join
     haz_no_info h2
     on ra.haz_id3 = h2.haz_id left join
     haz_no_info h3
     on ra.haz_id3 = h3.haz_id;
```

The `left join` is in case some of the descriptions don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Its Very Simple just use aliases name and join the table three times

```
 SELECT risk.risk_assessment_id as risk_id, risk.haz_id as haz_id_one, risk.haz_id_2 as      haz_id_two, risk.haz_id_3 as haz_id_three, one.haz_description as one_desc, two.haz_description as two_desc, three.haz_description as three_desc FROM risk 
LEFT JOIN haz as one ON one.haz_id = risk.haz_id
LEFT JOIN haz as two ON two.haz_id = risk.haz_id_2
LEFT JOIN haz as three ON three.haz_id = risk.haz_id_3
```

Comment: hi yeah i checked it but i keep getting the same error no matter which code i use it might be the way im echoing it out

Comment: Just echo it with the aliases name I have given in the query.You will get it. If you still have an issue please free feel to comment

Comment: echo $row['ops_id']. 
            $row['risk_id'].' '.
            $row['one_desc']. 
            $row['two_desc'].' '.
            $row['three_desc'];     By this way you csan display the is and three descriptions